# Корректность использования умных указателей

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, инспекция-кода, smart-pointer

Я только начал изучать умные указатели и написал функцию, которая вызывает контекстное меню по правому клику. Правильно ли я всё сделал, или может стоит что-то переделать?

```
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
    auto del = [](QMenu *m) { m->deleteLater(); };
    std::unique_ptr<QMenu, decltype(del)> sMenu(menu, del);

    auto infoA = sMenu.get()->addAction("Обновить");
    auto delA = [](QAction *a) { a->deleteLater(); };
    std::unique_ptr<QAction, decltype(delA)> sinfoA(infoA, delA);

    QObject::connect(sinfoA.get(), &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){
        updateProcesses();
    });
    sMenu.get()->exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Я не уверен, уместно ли задавать такие вопросы, но надеюсь, что нормально

Comment: Не уверен, что вызов `deleteLater` в данной ситуации будет правильным.

Comment: Как то не очень. unique_ptr вызовет деструктор как только выйдет за пределы блока (то есть, до ближайшей парной `}`). Потом объект будет помещен в очередь удаления и скорее всего он будет удален, когда пройдет очередная итеррация event loop (то есть, достаточно скоро).

Поэтому, вряд ли будет кому посылать сигнал triggered.

Comment: @KoVadim вызов exec заблокирует блок, пока я не закрою меню. Сам код-то работает как надо, у меня скорее вопрос по его качеству

Comment: не нужно блокировать. Подобные штуки часто вызывают дальнейшие баги. И поэтому, код плохой.

Comment: @KoVadim Вроде бы в Qt вызов диалоговых окон всегда подразумевает блокировку остального интерфейса. Предлагаете мне писать свою реализацию QMenu?

Comment: В любом случае, в данном случае можно просто создать объекты на стеке, если уже решили блокировать поток. И все Ваши трехстрочия превратятся в одну строку.

Comment: @KoVadim  с QAction это не получится, потому что я получаю указатель на объект, тут либо в лямбде его удалять, либо через умный указатель. Насколько я понимаю, деструктор QMenu не удаляет action'ы добавленные в него.

Comment: Он не удаляет, если его попросить. У QAction  в конструкторе есть параметр parent, Впишите туда указатель на объект QMenu. И теперь, удаление action  - это проблема деструктора menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хочу расстроить, но умные указатели тут **абсолютно** ни к чему. Всё делается в 4 с небольшим строчки:

```
QMenu menu;
QAction *update=menu.addAction("Обновить");
QObject::connect(update, &QAction::triggered, this, [this](){
    updateProcesses();
});
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```

- `QMenu` просто создаётся на стеке и безопасно удаляется по выходу из блока.
- `QMenu` сам удаляет все свои `QAction`'ы созданные с помощью перегруженных вариантов `addAction()` делать это вручную нет **никакого** смысла.